# Unix (process) creates a core file

Tags: windows, unix

I have a bit of a tricky situation. First of all I am a noob with no-to-little UNIX knowledge and experience. I work for a huge company with lots of security protocols and I can't debug or look into the source code of the programs. But I hope you guys can helps me get closer to the problem, so I can report it to the right person.

They have a very old piece of software running on a UNIX server. This program's task is to process data from a database and put log files on a network drive. Because the log files aren't very big and the software removes the old logs when putting up new ones the network drive is very limited in space. This program has always worked perfectly, but lately errors were generated that the program could not delete the old log files.

Also a file has been created which I assume is a core dump. The file is named `core.10042014100000` and a new one of these is created every hour (The program runs every hour). However, on a windows PC the file can not be read, copied and removed. (Not sure about the UNIX system, but I don't have access to that)

Can someone please help me come closer to finding out what is wrong? 
Like,Which process creates the core file?, Why is the core file created?, Why can't I do anything with it? and Could this have anything to do with the old logs not being removed?

Comment: Which version of Unix are you running? HP-UX/Solaris/AIX/BSD etc.?

Comment: @mtak AIX 5.2 and the Database Server is Oracle 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On AIX you can use the `dbx` command to analyze core files ([tutorial](http://delphiwww.cern.ch/~dellib/tutorial/node22.html)). On most Unices, if you run `file /path/to/core.10042014100000` it will tell you which process created the core file.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sending that to our UNIXMeister and Maybe he can get further.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this was the final step towards the answer. Thanks you very much!